# Looking for a book where there was a drug that permanently increased intelligence

Tags: story-identification, books

The premise of the book was there was this drug that would permanently increase your intelligence. It was very tightly controlled by the vaguely socialistic world government. The MC's twin brother had tried to take the drug, but was given a poison that turned him into a vegetable. There were various scenes in the MC's plot for revenge, including some kind of fight club in Hong Kong. The MC finally gets his revenge on the system by dosing the heads of the world government with the serum, knowing that increasing their intelligence will lead them to make beneficial changes that will eventually tear the system apart.

Comment: When did you read this?  Was it a paperback, hard cover, or e-book?

Answer (score 23):

I think this is probably [*The R-Master*](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3747) by Gordon R. Dickson (1973), later reprinted in an expanded version as *The Last Master* (1984).  As the book starts, the protagonist, Etter Ho, has the intelligence-augmenting drug R-47 administered to him.  Unfortunately, it sometimes causes a bad reaction, as it did to his brother Wally:

> ... Whether the R-47 should do anything for him or not, whether it should
> raise his intelligence a few I.Q. points or drop it, he wanted to be fully aware when the change was happening to him.  Even if freak chance should result in a severe loss of mental acuity, as it had with Wally, he wanted to be aware of that, too, when it came. ...

He lucks out and becomes a supergenius, an "R-Master":

> "You'll do for now," Et said.  "Tell me what's happened to me.  How much brighter am I?"
> Morgan Carwell looked uncomfortable.  He sat almost lumpily in the chair facing Et, a big brown man clearly struggling with himself.
> ...
> "An R-Master just gets a little more excited than all the rest when it comes to intellectual matters, is that it?" Et asked.  "I thought I was going to be something more than that."
> "You are," said Carwell.  "That's the point.  You Masters seem able to reach back into personal resources we wouldn't think you'd have.  Put it this way.  Ordinary subjects benefiting from R-47 can demonstrate remarkable feats of mental strength.  But R-Masters can demonstrate the equivalent of hysteric strength..."

He goes gambling in Hong Kong but finds duelists in a back room:

> The most elaborate gambling establishments of the mid-twenty-first century were maintained in and about what had been the old British crown colony of Hong Kong, as were the best-supplied stores and the most expensive health clubs and spas...
> The biggest and most famous of the gambling establishments, which included stores, health clubs, and hotel and restaurant space merely as sidelines, was the Sunset Hut, a construction of innumerable levels built up around the 280-meter-high Sunset Mountain on Lan Tao Island.
> ...
>  ... Et, still drunk on his own spurt of body adrenalin, pushed free of the security men, walked up to and past Rico and the man in black, and opened the door through which the other had come.
> He stepped into what seemed to be a balcony with seats overlooking a gym. ... Down on the floor of the gym itself, two men in black suits like those on the men in the corridor were engaged in a fencing match.

Later, Etter discovers that his brother was not given the normal R-47 drug:

> "As I said," Garranto went on, coming back across the room to stand before him, "I've got my work to do; I'll deny ever having this conversation with you, if it comes down to that.  But if I was a betting man, I'd bet that your brother had something administered to him other than the normal R-47 formula, and that other, whatever it was, was responsible for his mental decay and the fact that now he'll never recover from his present state."

Eventually Etter arranges to meet the Section Chiefs of the Earth Council, and doses them all with an improved version of R-47, R-50:

> "Of course I'm right," said Et swiftly.  "That's the one thing you overlooked in letting Malone and Rico Erm get away with the means to make the R-50.  The one group of people who'd really threaten the EC system if they were R-Masters are you people here."
> ...
> ... Inside was a small metal capsule.  Before any of the Field Examiners nearby could reach him, Wally took it in his fingers and tossed it onto the floor in the center of the horseshoe table.
> It exploded.

Etter Ho explains that this is sure to bring down the system, so the book ends happily:

> "Don't forget," said Et.  "This is crumbling the pyramid from the top down.  These people control the system.  Big chunks of it.  They'll end up using these chunks in rule-breaking ways and taking the chunks along with them into battle with each other.  In the end, the whole hierarchy will break up into anarchy.  Meanwhile, the R-50 that Lee and Rico will be making will be spreading and increasing the new crop of independent problem-solvers on the outside, ready to take over when the original system crumbles."

Comment: The conclusion that the ending is happy seems naive :)